# Dash from Plotly: Split figure legend and move to the right

Tags: plotly, legend, title, figure, plotly-dash

I have plotted a chart as attached and I want to add more line or barchart to the figure but the space remained for the legend is over. So, I want that the next legend be added to the right in the area were I wrote HERE in that box. What do do?
Please, look at the code for that title below[image]:

```
dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [trace1, trace2, trace4, trace5, trace6, trace7],
            'layout':
            go.Layout(
            title='', width="508", height="350", legend=dict(x=0, y=7), 
            margin={'l': 20, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 65},

            font=dict(
        family='sans-serif',
        size=8,
        color='#000'
    ),
```

Your help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: You can style your site using CSS. This will help you to get the job done.

Comment: Did you try adding `orientation='h'` to your `legend layout`?